# How to save image from HTML File-Element in a folder?

Tags: html, file, directory

I have an element like this:

```
<input type="file"  accept="image/*" id="fileAdd" name="image" size="30" />
```

How can I save the selected image in a folder inside the project?

Comment: You need a server side script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your form values to .php file.
Look for "move_uploaded_file()" function in php or another example (there's a lot of it on stackoverflow)